# How to understand where the error is in a SQL query that fails with this message Syntax error near 'INSERT INTO `

Tags: sql, mariadb

I need to run a SQL query that inserts some stuff in the table if the table has not a record with the name "Orders".
So far I did this:

```
IF NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT 
    *
  FROM
    gridconfigs
  WHERE
    gridconfigs.name = 'Orders'
)
INSERT INTO
  `gridconfigs` (
    `ownerId`,
    `classId`,
    `name`,
    `searchType`,
    `type`,
    `config`,
    `description`,
    `creationDate`,
    `modificationDate`,
    `shareGlobally`
  )
VALUES(
....
```

And this is the error I am getting:

```
Errore nella query (1064): Syntax error near 'INSERT INTO `gridconfigs` ( `ownerId`, `classId`, `name`, ...' at line 9
```

I do not get what the arror actually is.

Comment: What's your database engine? Valid syntax is relative to that.

Comment: @JeroenMostert I see in the docker file this about the db: db:
    image: mariadb:10.4, I imagine that is the database engine?

Comment: Indeed it is, and then it shouldn't be hard to find that [MariaDB's `IF` requires a `THEN`](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/if/).

Comment: I added the mariadb tag :-|

Comment: @JeroenMostert thank you. I am actually new to SQL and DB so I thought that SQL was the same regardless the DB

Comment: There is an SQL standard (ANSI SQL), but unfortunately not a single database on earth implements the standard, the whole standard and nothing but the standard; they all have quirks that require that you know what you're working with for anything beyond the most basic queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write a SELECT with the EXISTIS, instead of a INSERT INTO VALUES

```
CREATE TABLE   `gridconfigs` (
    `ownerId` int,
    `classId` int,
    `name` varchar(19),
    `searchType` int,
    `type` int,
    `config` int,
    `description` int,
    `creationDate` int,
    `modificationDate` int,
    `shareGlobally` int
  )
;
```

```
INSERT INTO gridconfigs
    
VALUES
(1,2,'Orders',4,5,6,7,8,9,10)
;
```

```
INSERT INTO
  `gridconfigs` (
    `ownerId`,
    `classId`,
    `name`,
    `searchType`,
    `type`,
    `config`,
    `description`,
    `creationDate`,
    `modificationDate`,
    `shareGlobally`
  )
    SELECT 
    1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10
    WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT 1 FROM gridconfigs  WHERE  gridconfigs.name = 'Orders')
```

> ```
> Records: 0  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0
> ```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/WN1TnFRQ)